# Plain TeX section number in margin

Tags: margins, plain-tex

I want to typeset the number for the section in the margin. Here's an MWE of what I'm starting from.

```
%  --- Fonts ------------------------------------------------
\font\0="Roboto Condensed Light" at 12pt\0
\font\ssa="Roboto Condensed Bold" at 24pt

%  --- Layout ------------------------------------------------
\raggedright
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1em

%  --- Structure ---------------------------------------------
\newcount\SectionNumber

\def\Section #1\par{%
\vskip 40pt
\advance \SectionNumber by 1
{\ssa\the\SectionNumber. #1}
\vskip 8pt
}

% Start Text
\Section Project One

\input knuth

\bye
```

[image: example-before-margin]

I'm looking at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224330/3611) and trying to adapt it here, so I came up with this:

```
\def\inmargin#1{\strut\vadjust{\kern-\dp\strutbox\smash{\llap{#1}}\kern\dp\strutbox}}

\def\Section #1\par{%
\vskip 40pt
\advance \SectionNumber by 1
{\ssa\inmargin{\the\SectionNumber. }#1}
\vskip 8pt
}
```

This is close, but when the section header has descenders it seems to be incorrectly aligned. See:

[image: badly-aligned]

As you can see, the 1. is a little below where it should be. The problem doesn't occur if I omit the descender:

[image]

I tried various contortions creating my own box and moving it around, and also trying to just kern the whole section heading negatively into the margin. I don't really care what approach is taken, I'd just like to understand what I'm missing. I suspect it has something to do with the height and depth of the section heading text.

Comment: Playing with the TeXbook, eh? Also, I'm no Plain user, but can't you put the number in a box, hskip `-\wd\thebox`, and then set the title on the same baseline?

Comment: @SeanAllred You are the Kwisatz Haderach!

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but I'll take that as a good thing `:)` l3coffins (`texdoc xcoffins`) has taught me everything I know `;)`

Comment: @SeanAllred it's a compliment, it's from Dune. I'll have to check out xcoffins, thanks!

Comment: @seanallred do you mind putting the code from your comment as an answer?

Comment: urk!  the roboto font doesn't handle tex-style ligatures.  instead of a nice en-dash, it gives you two vert bars in "large||scale"!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see what happens with your `\inmargin` macro:

```
\def\inmargin#1{%
  \strut
  \vadjust{
    \kern-\dp\strutbox
    \smash{\llap{#1}}%
    \kern\dp\strutbox
  }%
}
```

You emit a `\strut` that starts horizontal mode, because it does `\unhcopy\strutbox`. However, you should be aware of the fact that Plain does

```
\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt width0pt}
```

which is quite small, compared to `\ssa` which is a font at 24pt. Then you tell TeX that, after the paragraph has been typeset, after the first line of the paragraph (which is just the section title), a vertical kern of `-\dp\strutbox` (which is -3.5pt), a smashed box containing the section number and another kern (of 3.5pt) will be inserted. Now, if the section title has a descender it will be way more than 3.5pt, because it uses a large font.

The macro you are trying to modify is for adding something in the left margin without knowing the point where this addition is made. In your case you *do* know when the object in the margin must be announced: at the `\Section` command. So no trick is necessary: just `\llap` it.

However, `\llap` does `\hbox`, which is not a horizontal command, so you need to start it in some way. The correct way is to issue `\noindent`, that works independently of your setting to `\parindent`.

```
\def\Section#1\par{%
  % be in vertical mode
  \par
  % step the section number
  \global\advance\SectionNumber by 1
  % don't bother to add vertical space if there's already
  \ifdim\lastskip<40pt \removelastskip\penalty-400 \vskip40pt\fi
  % start horizontal mode without indent
  \noindent
  % print the section number
  \llap{\ssa\the\SectionNumber. }%
  % print the section title
  {\ssa\baselineskip=32pt \interlinepenalty=10000 #1\par}%
  % no page break
  \nobreak
  % some vertical space
  \vskip 8pt
}
```

Full example

```
%  --- Fonts ------------------------------------------------
\font\roboto="Roboto Condensed Light" at 12pt
\roboto
\font\ssa="Roboto Condensed Bold" at 24pt

%  --- Layout ------------------------------------------------
\raggedright
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1em

%  --- Structure ---------------------------------------------
\newcount\SectionNumber

\def\Section#1\par{%
  % be in vertical mode
  \par
  % step the section number
  \global\advance\SectionNumber by 1
  % don't bother to add vertical space if there's already
  \ifdim\lastskip<40pt \removelastskip\penalty-400 \vskip40pt\fi
  % start horizontal mode without indent
  \noindent
  % print the section number
  \llap{\ssa\the\SectionNumber. }%
  % print the section title
  {\ssa\baselineskip=32pt \interlinepenalty=10000 #1\par}%
  % no page break
  \nobreak
  % some vertical space
  \vskip 8pt
}

% Start Text
\Section Project One

\input knuth

\Section Project Two

\input knuth

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation of the code! This is really helping me understand TeX.

Answer (score 6):

You should be in horizontal mode when setting the sectional title. The following should work just fine:

```
\def\Section #1\par{%
\vskip 40pt
\advance \SectionNumber by 1
{\leavevmode\ssa\llap{\the\SectionNumber. }#1}
\vskip 8pt
}
```

Note the use of `\leavevmode` to enter horizontal mode.

Comment: Did the `\vskip` put me in vertical mode? Is `\llap` not sufficient to put me in horizontal mode?

Comment: @DanielLyons: Correct, `\llap` is insufficient dit getting into horizontal mode. In your example you're in vertical mode, yes. Although typically one would execute an explicit `\par` to achieve this under all circumstances.